# Instagram api getting photos without getting link

Tags: php, instagram-api

I need get photos and descriptions from registered instagram.
As I understand from docs on github https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API
You need put auth link first ant then using auth token after click on it you are redirected to some callback url, where you can get media then. But can I somehow login automatically without clicking link??
I have some

```
$instagram = new Instagram(array(
    'apiKey'      => 'apiKey',
    'apiSecret'   => 'apiSecret',
    'apiCallback' => 'apiCallback there'
));
```

with my data get after registration in https://www.instagram.com/developer/. How can I get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess try something like this:

```
        $userid = "User-ID-Goes-Here";
        $accessToken = "Token-Goes-Here";

    // Gets our data
    function fetchData($url){
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch); 
         return $result;
    }

    // Pulls and parses data.
    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}");
    $result = json_decode($result);
    //use data here
```

Source: http://blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-instagram-api-fancybox-simplified

Comment: It seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanx.